# Annotation events not update the chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

On my chart using Chart.js I have an annotation created with the chartjs-plugin-annotation. I would like the annotation label to be visible on hover over the line. But I can't get it to work. I have the following code:

```
//define ChartOneData
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");

var chartOne = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartOneData,
    options: {
        annotation: {
            events: ["mouseenter", "mouseleave"],
            annotations: [{
                type: 'line',
                mode: 'vertical',
                scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
                value: 1,
                label: {
                    enabled: false,
                    content: "Text Label",
                },
                onMouseenter: function(e) {
                    var element = this;
                    element.options.label.enabled = true;
                    element.chartInstance.update();
                },
                onMouseleave: function(e) {
                    var element = this;
                    element.options.label.enabled = false;
                    element.chartInstance.update();
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The events fire and change the attribute 'enabled' (visible in console testing) but the chart, and visuals, do not update.
In fact I receive the error in the console:

```
Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation.
dispatcher @ chartjs-plugin-annotation.js:261
```

I don't understand this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turned out that this was an issue with the underlying pluging. The code was correct and worked with chart.js versions 2.5 and 2.6 but not with 2.7. An issue was added to the chart-annotations github repository.

The solution was to downgrade to 2.6 and await a fix in the next version of charts.js

Comment: I had this exact issue and this fixed it, thank you for updating to include an answer @Attack68!

Comment: @MikelBitson what did you do to fix? Im interested, I never did manage to get it working besides downgrading..

Comment: I didn't fix it with 2.7; I downgraded to 2.6 and that allowed me to continue development.